# Modular arithmetic: Solving equation modulo prime number

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I have an equation $$x \cdot a \equiv b\pmod m$$ where $a$ and $b$ are known and $m$ is a prime number.

I want to solve for $x$. If $b=1$ then $x=a^{m-2}$ but I need to solve it for any value of $b$.

I found [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2894779/solving-the-congruence-20x-equiv-16-pmod92-and-giving-answer-as-a-congruen?rq=1) which seems to work but is there an easier way if $m$ is prime ?

Comment: Just multiply by b^(-1) and get it back to the form you easily know how to solve.

Comment: Ah, that was easy! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integers mod. $m$ are a field if $m$ is prime. So, as in any other field, multiply both sides by $a^{-1}$:

$$x\equiv b a^{-1}\equiv ba^{m-2}\pmod m. $$
Note $a$ may very well have an order  $< m-1 $. The only general result is that it is a divisor of $m-1$, and in real calculations, it may be useful to check its value.